# Does .NET Core handle correctly multiple classes/file instead of larger ones

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, architecture

Sorry it's more about a good practice question than an actual technical issue but I'm a bit concerned here and I need your opinion.

I'm a software engineer, mainly front-end but I started working on the back-end of my current project, which is in .NET Core, I'm having some discussion with the senior back-end developer here.

I'm completely for single-responsibility classes, unit-testing and extraction of logic that shouldn't fit the same class, but he tends to have larger functions/classes.

As we discussed he told me that .NET Core wasn't handling correctly a high number of classes/files and told me there would be performance impact. This seems unreal to me, as I've worked before on many other back-end languages and it was never raised as something that could impact the performance in a noticeable way.

Is there any way I can prove him wrong ( or right ? ) about that subject ? It's quite of a blocker for me as I'd love to increase general quality of code in the back-end.

Thank you for your answers, I'd be glad to read articles or anything related to the subject.

Comment: ASP.NET core itself consists of an enormous number of classes, almost all 1/file. It still does pretty well in the benchmarks.

Comment: That's ridiculous. As @HenkHolterman said, .NET Core itself fully embraces software engineering best practices, including SOLID principles. Fortunately, you can "prove" it by pointing him at Github for [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) and [ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet). Also, [.NET Core Performance Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thank you guys I've done my research with your links and got the approval to refactor :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

As per this article (Link below): 
.NET CORE should be used when the project demands a high performance and scalable system needs. Microsoft recommends running .NET Core with ASP.NET Core for the best performance and scale. This becomes important when hundreds of micro services could be used. A lower number of servers and virtual machines should be needed. The efficiency and scalability gained could translate to a better user experience in addition to cost savings.

Article: https://dzone.com/articles/net-core-vs-net-framework-how-to-pick-a-net-runtim